# BaseExpandablelist different groups with different backgrounds

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am making a listview with sections, using BaseExpandableListAdapter and making the group not to collapse. Now i want different groups (including header and rows) to have different background, Is it possible. I could only give background to header or rows but not to whole of the group.

Answer (score 0):

yes. it is possible if you customized `BaseExpandableListAdapter`.
see custom Expandible list view example from the following url
http://about-android.blogspot.com/2010/04/steps-to-implement-expandablelistview.html

Comment: I want background for whole of the group including header and rows, by using the method getGroupView i can only customize the header of the group.